# Adding SharePoint custom webpart error after install

Tags: javascript, powershell, sharepoint, web-parts

I'm having trouble adding a custom webpart to SharePoint. I'm using Powershell to install the wsp file. That works, the problem is when I add it to a site it says 'Web Part Error: A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. The type could not be found or it is not registered as safe.' I have read this most often means that it isn't in the web.config file under the  section but it is in there. Sometimes it does load and when it does it doesn't run the JavaScript in the webpart. What else can I check?

Thanks.

Comment: check if dll referenced by your project are in your .wsp package

Comment: Just checked, my dll is in the wsp.